# XPath only works if I add an extra node

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

I'm pretty new to using XML and very new to XPath.
I'm trying to select a field in my XML document and display that in a label on a webpage. Sound nice and simple.

Here is the code on my webpage:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="NewsListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewsDataSource">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ><%#XPath("temp1")%></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="NewsDataSource" runat="server" DataFile="~/news.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This works 100% fine when using a XML document like the one below.

```
<test>
  <response>
    <temp1>23.7</temp1> 
  </response>
 </test>
```

But the XML document I am trying to access, which I cannot change looks like this:

```
  <response>
    <temp1>23.7</temp1> 
  </response>
```

Basically the same document but without the extra node at the top.

Is there anyway I can get XPath to read the value of temp1 without the extra node?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with xpath but looking at documentation.. can you add

```
 <asp:Repeater 
        id="Repeater1" 
        runat="server" 
        DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("response") %>' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Adding XPath="/response" to the XMLDataSource did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this API before, but does it work to do something like this?

```
<%#XPath("temp1/text()")%>
```

This xpath should return the text of the temp1 element.